# Reflection.Emit Building a entity graph

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I have spent some time trying to building an entity graph dynamically with Reflection.Emit. Creating a assembly with a new flat type (class), instantiate it and use it with reflection  is easy and works fine. But when it comes to building a structure with generic lists of yet another dynamic classes, it gets more complicated and I got stuck. Basically, I would like to build the following structure dynamically:

```
public class Head
{
    public string HeadId { get; set; }
    public AssignmentType HeadType { get; set; }
    public int TestIndicator { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Head()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public List<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Descriptions = new List<Description>();
    }
}

public class Description
{
    public string DescriptionText { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public enum AssignmentType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC
}
```

Have been looking for numerous examples but so far I have not found anything addressing this. If someone have a sample or could point me in the right direction for solving this by using Reflection.Emit, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you show some of your emit code and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Have you considered using Activator.CreateInstance if you have a design time definition or the dynamic keyword or ExpandoObject if you only have a runtime definition?

Comment: Have you considered a higher-level approach using Roslyn or something like that? Reflection.Emit tends to be hard to get right.

Comment: svick, yes, Reflection.Emit is somewhat hard to get right indeed. I  looked at Roslyn and it seems very interesting, I managed to build my types successfully, and I will definitively invest more time investigating Roslyn. Thank you for pointing me in that direction. For this project though, I can´t use Roslyn since it still is a CTP and I am not allowed to use that in a production environment. In my project now I will go for the solution kkokosa posted below. Thank you for taking time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `CSharpCodeProvider` from `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace:

```
    string source = "public class Description" +
                    "{" +
                    "   public string DescriptionText { get; set; }" +
                    "   public string Country { get; set; }" +
                    "}";

    CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
    parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
    CompilerResults result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
    if (!result.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        Type type = result.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Description");
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will go for this solution in my project, it´s simple and do what I need. For some reason I have ignored the possibilities using CodeDom thinking that Reflection.Emit was the way to go. Thank you for enlightening me. I will use this for creating DTO objects during runtime using meta data from a provider that uses entity framework poco´s.